Maven Build Fails with Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.2.0 Error in GitHub Actions
Encountering an issue while trying to build and deploy a Mule application to Anypoint Platform via GitHub Actions. The build fails with the following error:
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:jar:4.2.0
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule-application @ line 12, column 13
...
[ERROR] The project com.[redacted]:1.0.0 (/home/runner/work/[redacted]/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:jar:4.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:pom:4.2.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [mulesoft-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/, default, releases), mulesoft-snapshots (http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/, default, releases+snapshots)]
...


Here is the current pom.xml configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.templates</groupId>
        <artifactId>templates-tooling-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.24</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.[redacted]</groupId>
    <artifactId>[redacted]</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <name>[redacted]</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>
        <app.name>[redacted]</app.name>
        <env>[redacted]</env>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.2.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
        <munit.version>3.0.0</munit.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <tag>v1.0.0</tag>
    </scm>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-secure-configuration-property-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
            <version>10.20.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-scripting-module</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sap-s4hana-cloud-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange V3</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>coverage-report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                    <cloudHubDeployment>
                        <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
                        <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
                        <username>${anypoint.username}</username>
                        <password>${anypoint.password}</password>
                        <applicationName>${app.name}</applicationName>
                        <environment>{env}</environment>
                        <workerType>MICRO</workerType>
                        <workers>1</workers>
                        <objectStoreV2>true</objectStoreV2>
                        <properties>
                            <secure.key>${decryption.key}</secure.key>
                        </properties>
                    </cloudHubDeployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Tried changing the mule-maven-plugin version from 4.2.0 to 4.1.1.
Added mirrors to settings.xml to ensure that all requests to the MuleSoft releases/snapshots repository use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

These steps have not resolved the issue.
Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the issue here?
Are there additional configurations needed in settings.xml or pom.xml to resolve dependencies correctly?
Thanks
